# Examples of "natural" finitely generated groups with an undecidable conjugacy problem

Tags: gr.group-theory, computability-theory

I am looking for natural groups with undecidable conjugacy problem. By natural, I mean that the word problem should be decidable, and the group should be given by some natural action. I know that $\mathbb{Z}^d \rtimes F_m$ (with a suitable action of $F_m$) has undecidable conjugacy problem. That's very nice, but I'd like to know other examples. I do not care about finite presentation, and I'm also fine with the group being a f.g. *subgroup* of something natural and geometric, which maybe simplifies things. A concrete case I was not able to resolve is whether all f.g. subgroups of right-angled Artin groups have decidable conjugacy problem.

*Šunić, Zoran; Ventura, Enric*, [**The conjugacy problem in automaton groups is not solvable.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2012.04.014), J. Algebra 364, 148-154 (2012). [ZBL1261.20034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1261.20034).

Comment: It's trivial that all f.g. subgroups of RAA groups have decidable word problem. If you meant conjugacy, it's known that some f.g. subgroup of $F_2\times F_2$ has unsolvable conjugacy problem.

Comment: It was indeed a typo. Your latter sentence then solves my question completely. Could you write it out? Apologies if this was too easy.

Comment: You can find a reference to the $F_2 \times F_2$ result in C.F.'s Miller's book/thesis from 1971. Miller also showed that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are recursively enumerable subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, then $S_1$ is Turing reducible to $S_2$ if and only if there exists a f.g. recusrively presented group whose word problem has the Turing degree $S_1$ and whose conjugacy problem has the Turing degree of $S_2$. You might be interested in this (and the construction is rather straightforward modulo the naturality of a group with undecidable conjugacy problem).

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the reference! The latter result I've heard of, can you do that in a RAAG as well, or is there some HNN magic or the like?

Comment: References to Miller are [19] and [20] here: https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.4331

Comment: My own interpretation of the fact that there are f.g. subgroups of $F_2\times F_2$ with undecidable conjugacy problem, is not that they are "natural" instances of f.g. groups with undecidable conjugacy problem, but rather that they are "non-natural" f.g. subgroups of $F_2\times F_2$... of course "natural" is subjective!

Comment: @YCor: We agree, it's just that this question is a compromise between a good question of general interest and me actually just needing a very specific thing for boring reasons.

Comment: If $N$ is a finitely generated torsion-free normal subgroup of a hyperbolic group $H$ such that $H/N$ has undecidable word problem, then $N$ has undecidable conjugacy problem. Therefore, Rips' construction gives many examples of f.g. groups with decidable word problem but undecidable conjugacy problem. (However, the groups are not f.p., and their "natural"-ness is debatable!). Reference is: Theorem 1.2 of A. Martino, and A. Minasyan. "Conjugacy in normal subgroups of hyperbolic groups." Forum Mathematicum. Vol. 24. No. 5. De Gruyter, 2012 ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1515/form.2011.089)).

Comment: (This is probably related to the $F_2\times F_2$ example, although Martino and Minasyan do use properties of hyperbolic groups in their proof. However, their proof is pleasantly short, and the properties used are pretty basic (e.g. an element has finite index in its centraliser, etc.) so it may generalise.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chuck Miller in [Miller, Charles F., III *On group-theoretic decision problems and their classification*. Annals of Mathematics Studies, No. 68. Princeton University Press, Princeton, N.J.; University of Tokyo Press, Tokyo, 1971] proves the following two rather nice and natural examples.

**Theorem III.10.** The free product of two free groups with finitely generated amalgamation can have unsolvable conjugacy problem. Further, the finitely presented HNN extension of a free group can have unsolvable conjugacy problem.

(Note that Miller calls HNN extensions 'Strong Britton extensions').

Now by Bass-Serre theory, there is a natural action of an amalgamated free product/HNN on the associated Bass-Serre tree, which should satisfy your "natural action" criterion.

---

Edit: The result mentioned by YCor can also be found in Miller's book.

**Theorem III.23** The group $F_2 \times F_2$ has a finitely generated subgroup with undecidable conjugacy problem.

An important side remark, however, is that $F_2 \times F_2$ itself has decidable conjugacy problem, as do all RAAGs, in linear time. See [Crisp, John; Godelle, Eddy; Wiest, Bert; *The conjugacy problem in subgroups of right-angled Artin groups.* J. Topol. 2 (2009), no. 3, 442–460.].

Comment: This is nice, but not quite as nice as I understood from the comments, i.e. literal subgroup of RAAG.

Comment: (I guess this is, nicer in a different direction.)

Comment: This is a different example. There are also f.g. subgroups of $F_2 \times F_2$ which have undecidable conjugacy problem; I wanted to give YCor some time to write that answer up.

Comment: Gotcha! I did realize this has nicer generators (presumably).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda no, feel free to expand your own post, I don't need to answer just to provide a reference. Actually I don't know these examples (unlike the membership issue in f.g. subgroups of $F_2^2$ which I understand).

Comment: @VilleSalo Miller gives explicit generators and relations (modulo the generators and relations for a f.p. group with undecidable word problem). It should not be too horrible to work through to get an explicit presentation (and also Bass-Serre tree), though I have not done this.

Comment: @YCor I don't understand the examples well; they are quite artificial, and tie together several constructions, but the overall strategy is not too different from the membership problem, afaik.

Comment: I think these F2xF2 examples are also related to the free abelian group semidirect product free group examples. I vaguely remember a talk by Ventura and he said something to that effect maybe using that F_2xF_2 ends in GL_4(Z).  This may be nonsense.  It was long ago

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Certainly $F_2 \times F_2$ at least embeds in GL$_6(\mathbb{Z})$. But not the other way around, and I was precisely hoping for something slightly simpler than the semidirect product example (which I learned about from an MO post of yours).

Comment: (On a second reading, I guess you were suggesting something more specific with your comment which I didn't understand, and were just stating the embeddability in GL$_4(\mathbb{Z})$ as a fact.)

Comment: You can embed F_2 in GL_2 and hence F_2xF_2 into GL_4 by direct sum. They my belief is they embed the undecidable issues of F_2xF_2 in the orbit problem but maybe I am wrong

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: The undecidability of the conjugacy problem in semidirect products $\mathbb{Z}^d \rtimes F_m$ by Sunic-Ventura uses orbit-undecidability, which comes from a result of https://ddd.uab.cat/pub/prepub/2007/hdl_2072_9160/Pr766.pdf which in turn uses $F_2 \times F_2$ and Mihajlova's trick.

Comment: OK. I remembered a reduction to F_2xF_2 but didn't remember the details